# Add a combobox in to listview control in c++ builder

Tags: c++builder, vcl

I want to create a listview with 2 columns. in the first column it must be the row number and in the second number it should contains a combobox. I write the following code, but second column just show "combo" string. it does not show any combo box. what is the wrong?

```
for (int   i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

TListItem *items;
items= this->ListView1->Items->Add();
items->Caption=IntToStr(i);

items->SubItems->AddObject("combo"+IntToStr(i),(TObject *)this->ComboBox1);

}
```

Comment: Just to note, try avoid C-cast and use C++ casts

Answer (score 3):

It does not show a `TComboBox` because you have not actually set the `TComboBox` to be a child control of the `TListView`.  All you have done is store the `TComboBox` pointer as a user-defined value associated with the `TListItem`.  That has no effect on the UI, so get rid of it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    TListItem *items = ListView1->Items->Add();
    items->Caption = IntToStr(i);
    items->SubItems->Add("combo"+IntToStr(i));
}
```

To actually show a `TComboBox` inside of the `TListView`, you have to assign the `TListView` as the `Parent` of the `TComboBox`, and then use the `SetBounds()` method to position and size the `TComboBox` whenever you need to show it:

```
ComboBox1->Parent = ListView1;
...
RECT rect = {0};
ListView_GetSubItemRect(ListView1->Handle, SomeListItem->Index, 1, LVIR_BOUNDS, &rect);
ComboBox1->SetBounds(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right-rect.left, rect.bottom-rect.top);
// update ComboBox1->Items as needed...
ComboBox1->Visible = true;
...
ComboBox1->Visible = false;
```

With that said, what you are attempting to do is better handled using the `TValueListEditor` component instead.  Add items to it as needed, then use its `ItemProps` property to set each item's `TItemProp.EditStyle` property to `esPickList`, and then use the `TValueListEditor.OnGetPickList` event or the `TItemProp.PickList` property to manage the ComboBox strings as needed.